# Visual Studio 2008 marks solution files as version 10.00

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2010, versions

After trying out VS2010b2 also my VS2008 installation changes the versions of solution and project files to "Version 10.00". The MSBuild.exe on our CI Server does not support them.
Is there a way to make VS2008 generate .sln files with version number 9.00 again?

I know I can fix that manually. But each time I open a solution, the version gets changed back, which is annoying.

Cheers,

bja

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS2008 *should* generate v10 files; that's its native format version. VS2010 generates v11 solution file format. v9 was VS2005. I doubt that VS2008 has ever generated v9 files for you.

If you're using VS2008, your CI server should have .NET 3.5 installed, and that version of MSBuild should cope with v10 solution files.

Comment: The solution file starts as follows:
"Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
..."

But I was wrong about the project files. They still are version 9.*

Comment: @bja: Version 10 is correct for 2008 solution files. You'll find that 2010 generates version 11 files. The solution file version number isn't the same as the product version number - which I know is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that .NET 3.5 is installed on your CI server, and check the path to MSBuild.  Because .NET installs side-by-side, you may not have updated the path to MSBuild, and you could be using the old version.  Make sure that you're using the MSBuild which is located at  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5.  That will be able to build any version of MSBuild (earlier than VS 2010 of course)

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. I had the hudson configuration pointing to the MSBuild binary in the v2.0.50727 folder.